# Error list indices must be integers or slices, not list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy desarrollando un programa que organice una matriz de 100000 elementos con el algoritmo de ordenamiento por inserción, para que el código no tenga tiempos de ejecución muy elevados estoy utilizado un modelo de divide y vencerás, dividendo la matriz para luego insertarla en una matriz bidimensional, pero al momento de querer insertar la posición del valor en la matriz me marca este error list indices must be integers or slices, not list (osea por ejemplo divido 100 // 10 y el valor es 10, entonces se agregaria el valor 100 en la posicion 10 algo asi matriz[10].append(100))

```
import random

def generar_numeros():
    numeros = []
    while True:
        numero = random.randrange(1,201)
        if (numero not in numeros):
            numeros.append(numero)
            if(len(numeros) == 100):
                break
     return numeros

def posicion(arreglo):
    numeros = list(map(lambda x: x // 10, arreglo))
    return numeros

def divide_y_venceras(posicion, arreglo):   
    matriz = [0] * 10
    print(matriz)

   for i in range(10):
       matriz[i] = [] 
       matriz[posicion].append(arreglo)
   ordenamiento_por_insercion(matriz)
   print (matriz)

lista = generar_numeros()
print(lista)
print("##################################")
pos = posicion(lista)
print(pos)
print("##################################")
print(divide_y_venceras(pos,lista))
```

Comment: Ya revisaste que no sea una tupla lo que manejas? Las tuplas son fijas

Answer (score 0):

el error te dice que puedes acceder a los elementos de las listas usando enteros o usando slices.

```py
L = [5, 2, -1, 20]
# Estas formas son correctas
b = L[2]   # b=1
c = L[1:3] # c = [2, -1]
# Esto es incorrecto
d = L[[1, 0]]  # No se puede acceder usando una lista de indices
```

Esto podrias hacerlo si en vez de lista tienes un elemento de numpy, np.ndarray.

Una forma de como puedes acceder a los indices de una lista a travez de una lista es usando *list comprehesion*

```py
e = [L[x] for x in [1, 0]] # e = [2, 5]
```